# React native network error (CORS) when using Chrome developer tools but working with react-native-debugger

Tags: react-native, axios, google-chrome-devtools

All requests seem to work when using react native debugger but when attempting to use chrome debugger at `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` I get:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:<my_api_url>' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

and a network error.

[image]

I tried:

- CORS Chrome extension
- adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*'` or `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  true`
- Axios body is set to `undefined` as recommended in Axios library issues.
- accessing debugger with localhost IP like: `http://192.168.0.101:8081/debugger-ui/`

but the CORS error is still there.

This seem to be related to something that Chrome debugger does differently than `react-native-debugger`....

I examined the headers for both debuggers and they look exactly the same:

```
Accept: "application/json"
Accept-Language: "en"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Content-Type: "application/json"
X-API-Client: "my-app:10.3.0-null-dev-devbuild"
```

Error shows up on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Are you running on device? Try `http://DEVICE-IP:8081/debugger-ui/`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @FlorinDobre, you got the solution?

Comment: No, I am now using Flipper or Rn-debugger. Couldn't make it work with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a browser feature, servers need to opt into CORS to allow browsers to bypass same-origin policy. You can try updating React Devtools or you can raise an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Component%3A+Developer+Tools%2CType%3A+Bug%2CStatus%3A+Unconfirmed&template=devtools_bug_report.yml&title=%5BDevTools+Bug%5D%3A+).